# additional arguments ignored in stop()

Tags: r, cran

I would like to change the default value of the `call.` argument in `stop()` when called form inside my package. Therefore the packages includes a (non exported) version of `stop` that uses another default:

```
stop <- function(..., call. = FALSE, domain = NULL){
  base::stop(..., call. = call., domain = domain);
}
```

This does what I intended for `stop("my error")`. However when `stop` is called with a condition object, it gives an additional warning:

```
> stop(simpleError("foo"))
Error: foo
In addition: Warning message:
 In base::stop(..., call. = call., domain = domain) :
 additional arguments ignored in stop()
```

The error is raised by r-base in [stop.R](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/base/R/stop.R). How can I write a `stop` function that behaves exactly the same as `base::stop`, apart from a different default for the `call.` argument?

Comment: How are you calling your version of `stop` to produce this error? (if I go `stop('foo', 'bar')` I don't get the warning you mention)

Comment: Have you considered switching the order of the argument? Try calling `base::stop(call. = call., domain = domain, ...)`. It could be a weird parameter order/overwriting issue.

Comment: @Robert that would change the meaning of `stop("my error")`

Comment: That check in `base::stop` also checks `inherits(args[[1L]], "condition")` -- are you calling `stop` with a caught error somewhere?

Comment: Ah yes! I get it now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`base::stop` will always give that warning if you call it with a condition (e.g. caught error from a `tryCatch`) as its argument *and* supply `call.` or `domain`.

This is because of the check in `base::stop`

```
if (length(args) == 1L && inherits(args[[1L]], "condition")) {
    ....
    if (nargs() > 1L) # give the warning
```

where `args` is your `...`.

For the `call.` argument, `stop` takes this from the error object itself rather than from the `call.` argument to `stop` (hence the warning you are getting)::

```
stop(simpleError('achtung!'))
# Error: achtung!
stop(simpleError('achtung!'), call.=F) # gives the warning
# Error: achtung!
# In addition: Warning message:
# In stop(simpleError("achtung!"), call. = F) :
#   additional arguments ignored in stop()
stop(simpleError('achtung!', call=call('f')))
# Error in f() : achtung!
```

Depending on how the error in your particular code is constructed, you can set `call` to `NULL` in the creation of the error to suppress it in the call to `stop`.

You could either:

- modify your code that calls `stop(someConditionObject)` to just call `stop` with that object's *message* (so that the call is not passed through)
- modify your `stop` to test if `inherits(args[[1L]], "condition")` and set the call to `NULL` if `call.=F` to suppress it (`error$call <- NULL`), *and* then call `base::stop(error)` without the `call.` argument.